# SFTP as a different user than you logged in with

Tags: nautilus, ssh, sudo, sftp

I connect to my work machine over SSH. Sometimes I transfer files back and forth using using Nautilus' *"Connect to Server"* feature. Sometimes I change to the `root` user and run commands. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do both.

If I want to transfer files, I connect to the following server from nautilus:

```
sftp://andreas@work/home/andreas
```

The SSH configs are set up to NOT allow you to log in as root (moreover, `root` doesn't even have any entries in the `authorized_users` file). However, if I want to log in is root, since `andreas` is in the sudoers group, I can do like this:

```
andreas@home:~$ ssh andreas@work
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
andreas@work:~$ su
Password: [entered password]
root@work:/home/andreas#
```

The problem is, how do I combine these two, allowing me to browse the remote file system over an SSH connection, but as `root` (a different user than the one I logged in with, in this case, `andreas`)?

Comment: I don't think you can. The sftp backend can't do `su`, so to browse as root you should be able to login as root.

Comment: @Rmano Does SFTP use SSH, or does it have its own protocol? If it is the former, couldn't it use an existing tunnel or "continue off" after the existing SSH has authenticated as root?

Comment: I'm not an expert --- but when you use `su` in the ssh connection, you have a **shell** with superuser privileges --- ssh is completely oblivious to that. Now, I do not know if you can start some strange tunnel from the root shell to do what you want.